# Determination of the work mode with the project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vsix, vs-extensibility

In Visual Studio 2017 it is possible to work in a mode ‘Folder View’. This is the mode that runs when opening folder (File – Open – Folder...). You can also switch to it using the 'Solution Explorer' (switching from a 'Solution View' to 'Folder View').

Is it possible to programmatically determine (and if so, then how) what mode is enabled at the moment?

I saw the `IVsSolutionEvents7` interface, which contains methods that are called, for example, when opening or closing a folder (File – Open – Folder / Close Folder), but have not found anything that would help in addressing the problem described above.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [__VSPROPID7.VSPROPID_IsInOpenFolderMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.__vspropid7?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) on an IVsSolution reference, with a code like this:

```
var solution = (IVsSolution)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsSolution));

// __VSPROPID7 needs Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.15.0.DesignTime.dll nuget
// folderMode will be a boolean
solution.GetProperty((int)__VSPROPID7.VSPROPID_IsInOpenFolderMode, out object folderMode);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to detect switching between the ‘Folder view’ and ‘Solution view’ modes?

Comment: @Nightwalker - You can cast solution into a IVsSolution7 and use its OpenFolder method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution7.openfolder

Comment: Perhaps, I wasn't clear enough. I meant that I wanted to track the moment of user switching from ‘Folder View’ to ‘Solution View’. May be there are interfaces for this, in which the methods are defined, whose call occurs right when switching the modes. For example, in 'IVsSolutionEvents7' there are methods 'OnAfterOpenFolder' and 'OnBeforeCloseFolder', which are called when opening/closing a folder, but not when switching the mode in 'SolutionExplorer'.

Comment: @Nightwalker - There are all the other IVsSolutionEvents that you can use, OnAfterOpenSolution, OnAfterCloseSolution.

Comment: These methods aren't called when switching from the mode 'Solution View' to 'Folder View' and vice versa.